# What is the Difference Between argf and atan2f in C++?

Tags: c++, fft, std, complex-numbers

I am working on a project using FFT math, running into a situation where I need to calculate the phase angle of the real and imaginary FFT components. In some examples I see people using atan2f to do this, and in some I see people using argf alongside the complex number class.

Is there any difference in the way these two functions operate other than taking two separate arguments versus a single complex number argument? If so, what is the difference?

Have been scouring various documentation online and can't seem to find a clear or concise answer to this question.

Thanks!

This source was particularly confusing:

> If no errors occur, returns the phase angle of z in the interval [−π; π].
> Errors and special cases are handled as if the function is implemented as std::atan2(std::imag(z), std::real(z)).

This isn't clear whether they are equivalent in all cases, or only when there is an edge case or an error.

Comment: The obvious error case is `0+0i` There is a link [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/atan2) which describes the corner cases and over/underflow for `atan2`. I would expect `std::arg` to do the same as `atan2` for those

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/arg clearly indicates that `arg` could be implemented by calling `atan2`, and I’d think implementations would be idiotic if they didn’t (because they’d be implementing the same thing twice).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[[complex.value.ops]p4](https://wg21.link/complex.value.ops#4):

> ```cpp
> template<class T> T arg(const complex<T>& x);
> ```
>
> *Returns*: The phase angle of `x`, or `atan2(imag(x), real(x))`.

There is no difference, `std::arg(std::complex(x, y))` is `std::atan2(y, x)`.

If your complex number happens to not have a phase (e.g, `NaN+1j` or `0+0j`), `std::arg` will follow the results of `std::atan2` on those arguments.

Comment: “If your complex number happens to not have a phase, `std::arg` will follow the results of `std::atan2`” Otherwise it will also follow the result of `std::atan2`. Why the condition?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Just addressing the quote "Errors and special cases are handled as if the function is implemented as std::atan2(std::imag(z), std::real(z))." in the original question